# Google Books as a text source?

Tags: discussion, notability-of-sources

Given that Google, on [occasion](http://www.dnaindia.com/scitech/1815392/report-google-s-spring-cleaning-including-reader-all-that-s-shutting-down-in-2013), shuts down their little projects- should I be using their Books subsite as a source?

I did it twice in an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34313/where-do-the-bodies-of-the-dead-tributes-go/34314#34314), and I get antsy with overly-long generated links as it is [one aspect could be a session-id that's going to expire, and negate the link?], and have done it a few times recently.

And I don't want to link to another 'project' of Google's that will disappear in two years.  Articles here should be as **permanent as possible**.

The alternatives to Google Books are often else-country from publisher and sketchy at best.

Comment: I used Google books for an answer once too. Of course this was before they started stripping all their useful apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a gut feeling, but I get the impression that Google isn't going to shut down Books.

If I am wrong, we can do maintenance editing on older questions. There just aren't any other book websites that are suitable.

Comment: Another point, we're normally given notice, and we can look through those answers/questions citing them and screenshot/find an alternative in a time we are given notice.

Comment: I'm thinking about it- the Reader service was a dynamic service.  Needs continuous storage-writes.  Books is an established archive.  If they end adding to it, then they still have the archive and ad-ops.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, as long as you state the title and author of the book and insert the relevant excerpt into your answer, it shouldn't matter if Google Books survives or not.

Personally, I link to the main page of the book on Google Books which provides a search option. This provides an overview of the book, a short URL sans session IDs, and a search box where strings from the excerpt can be looked up.

Comment: Yep.  I did that, until I found a little way around needing to do it [I think].  I'm going to monitor that- and I'll have to use the main-page method if it starts failing.  The 'trick'- don't use the link that you think will work when you have a page-specific hit.  Bounce back out to Google general search, then use 'google books [book name] [reference text]'- if that doesn't work, swap [reference text] with [page-number].  I had to edit my answer after I second-guessed.

Answer (score 1):

Given that they're spending [$125 million to placate the Author's Guild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Book_Search_Settlement_Agreement) to keep Google Books operating, not to mention the actual scanning costs, I find it rather unlikely that that they'd just shut it down on a whim.